# How to display the value of a variable using remix debugger and emit

Tags: remix, events

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract test {
    event test_value(uint256 indexed value1);
    uint256 value_test;

     function test_f() public {

        //value_test processing
        emit test_value(value_test); // log the current value
    }
}
```

Can some body please guide me how to display the value of "value_test" using Remix debugger or emit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Deploy and Run Transactions
2. Deploy Contract
3. test_f
4. Debug
5. logs
6. value1: 0

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: At  https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js, I am seeing Compile, Run,... tabs. Then there is drop down arrow showing "test" and below it is "Deploy" or "At Address  with a text box" tab. In deployed contract, it shows me "test at 0x692...777(memory) . I can't find test_f.

Comment: Sorry I dont know which online tool you are using.

Comment: I used the newer version of Remix.

Comment: The process is about the same in the previous version. Visually different, for sure.

Comment: https://remix.ethereum.org

Comment: Sir, I can do step1 & step2 but I can't see test_f anywhere. I can see" test at 0x0dc..97caf(memory)" box but no test_f under it. Please guide me how you got test_f.

Comment: You see the contract at 0x97... you have to expand the tile to see the functions.

Comment: Look for the little arrow by the contract to open it.